# Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, webmatrix

I am developing with **WebMatrix 2.0 RC** and love it. I'm sure the database is set up correctly, but I'm getting this error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime
>
> error '800a01b6'
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'id'
>
> /myfile.asp, line 24

**MYFILE.ASP**

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<%
    set db = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    db.open "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & server.mappath("/App_Data/databasefile.sdf")
%>

<%
set grs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
grs.Open "SELECT * FROM gells", db
do until grs.EOF
    for each x in grs.Fields
        response.write("<table style='margin-bottom:8px;'><tr><td style='vertical-align:top; padding-top:4px;'><img src='gells/uploads/gelthumbs/" & x.id & "_gelthumb.jpg' style='border:1px solid #FFFFFF;' /></td><td style='vertical-align:top; padding-left:4px; text-align:justify;'><strong>" & x.title & "</strong><br />" & x.info & "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align:right; padding-top:4px;'><a href='gells.php?gelsid=" & x.id & "' ><img src='gells/viewgell.png' style='border:none;' /></a></td></tr></table>")
    next
    grs.MoveNext
loop
grs.close
%>
```

Comment: A suggestion - you should really use the ASP.NET Web Pages framework rather than classic ASP with WebMatrix. Classic ASP hasn't been developed for more than 10 years and a lot of simple things like file uploading or image manipulation require third party components in classic ASP. Start here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: @MikeBrind My job has ASP Classic sites. I am looking forward to ASP.NET and I'm sure my boss will switch if it gets the job done faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` variable in your code will be a Field object.  A field object does not have an `id` property hence the error.  I suspect that `id`, `title` and `info` are actually the names of the fields you want to use.  Hence your code should look like this:

```vbs
grs.Open "SELECT id, title, info FROM gells", db  
do until grs.EOF  
    response.write "<table style='margin-bottom:8px;'><tr><td style='vertical-align:top; padding-top:4px;'><img src='gells/uploads/gelthumbs/" _
        & Server.URLEncode(grs("id")) _
        & "_gelthumb.jpg' style='border:1px solid #FFFFFF;' /></td><td style='vertical-align:top; padding-left:4px; text-align:justify;'><strong>" _
        & Server.HTMLEncode(grs("title")) _
        & "</strong><br />" & Server.HTMLEncode(grs("info")) _
        & "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align:right; padding-top:4px;'><a href='gells.php?gelsid=" _
        & Server.URLEncode(grs("id")) _
        & "' ><img src='gells/viewgell.png' style='border:none;' /></a></td></tr></table>"
    grs.MoveNext  
loop  
grs.close
```

Note the SQL only includes the fields you need, also never send unencoded data directly from the DB.